# Does this use of reinterpret_cast invoke an undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

The basic idea is to create a variable size array, fixed at construction time and another class in a single allocation unit in order to reduce overhead and improve efficiency. A buffer is allocated to fit the array and another object and placement new is used to construct them. In order to access the elements of the array and the other object a pointer arithmetic and reinterpret_cast are used. 
That seems to work (at least in gcc), but my reading of the standard (5.2.10 Reinterpret Cast) tells me it's an undefined behavior. Is that correct? And if so, is there any way to implement this design without UB?

Full compilable example is here: http://ideone.com/C9CCa8

```
// a buffer contains array of A followed by B, laid out like this
// | A[N - 1] ... A[0] | B |

class A
{
    size_t index;
//...
// using reinterpret_cast to get to B object
    const B* getB() const 
    { 
        return reinterpret_cast<const B*>(this + index + 1); 
    }
};

class B
{
    size_t a_count;
//...
    virtual ~B() {}
// using reinterpret_cast to get to the array member
    const A* getA(size_t i) const 
    { 
        return reinterpret_cast<const A*>(this) - i - 1; 
    }
};

// using placement new to construct all objects in raw memory
B* make_record(size_t a_count)
{
    char* buf = new char[a_count*sizeof(A) + sizeof(B)];
    for(auto i = 0; i < a_count; ++i)
    {
        new(buf) A(a_count - i - 1);
        buf += sizeof(A);
    }
    return new(buf) B(a_count);
}
```

Comment: Use an object pool if you really need the performance. This is horrible and will be a debugging nightmare.

Comment: Why not add a vector of A into your B class?

Comment: This might give you odd addresses and end up in unaligned memory access. It might work in some platforms.

Comment: Answer to first two: 1)memory pool will hardly improve the performance, because it won't improve locality; 2) vector comes with overhead and performance penalty that the code tries to avoid, array<A> can't be used because the size known only at construction time.

Comment: Not directly your ?, but some points re this low level practice, if your use case calls for it. Suggestion: use LCM of sizeof(A) and sizeof(B) to position start of 2nd object type(B). Remember to disallow normal instantiate, delete, copy/move and arrays of type B. Use factory function returning specialized smart pointer with customized delete handling to create/manage objects.

Answer (score 5):

When using placement new, it's up to you to ensure the target memory is properly aligned for your data type, otherwise it is undefined behavior. After an array of A's, it is not guaranteed that the alignment of buf will be correct for an object of type B. Your use of reinterpret_cast is also undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior doesn't mean it won't work. It may for a particular compiler, and a particular set of class types and pointer offsets, etc. But you cannot put this code in an arbitrary standard-conformant compiler and guarantee it will work.

Use of these hacks strongly suggests you have not designed your solution properly.

Comment: In his example, there is no alignment problem, but there easily could be.  In the typical case, there won't be one today, but some change down the road will create one.  His use of `reinterpret_cast` is conform, however, _if_ the alignment constraints are met.  (And I fully endorse your last paragraph.)

Comment: With regards to the alignment problem: the implementation of `std::basic_string` in g++ does something similar.  And core dumps if you try `std::basic_string<double>` (at least on a Sparc).

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, my reading of the standard also suggest using reinterpret_cast is an undefined behavior. The alignment requirements can be statically asserted, so at least it won't go unnoticed. Regarding properly designing this, I'm all ears :-)

Comment: @GeneBushuyev I made some suggestions in the question comments. Have you profiled to determine such extreme measures are necessary?

Comment: @Neil Kirk -- I agree, profiling is an important step. It's not my code, but I need to form (and correct) my opinion, that's why the questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting question.  The question is what does `this
+ index + 1` point to.  If it really is a `B`, there should be
no problem (assuming that an `A*` is sufficiently large to
contain a `B*` without loss of value): "Converting a prvalue of
type 'pointer to T1' to the type 'pointer to T2' (where T1 and
T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2
are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type
yields the original pointer value." (§5.2.10/7)  Since you've
used the same expression (basically) to obtain the address at
which you construct the `B`, the only thing you can legally do
with `this + index + 1` is to convert it back to a `B*`.

But since you need the `index` variable in each element anyway,
why not save it as a pointer, rather than an index.

And in the end: this is a horrible solution with regards to code
readability, and robustness.  In particular, if `B` has stricter
alignment requirements than `A`, you can easily end up with the
`B` misaligned.  And if you change anything down the road, `B`
might end up with stricter alignment requirements.  I'd avoid
this solution at all costs.

Comment: The pointer could eliminate first reinterpret_cast, but index is required from A objects anyway, so it would increase size of A. Alignment can be statically asserted, so far I haven't seen violations.

Comment: The 5.7.10/7 seem to indicate that reinterpret_cast can do A*->B*->A*, which isn't the case here, also the B type is not standard layout.

Comment: A*->B*->A* is guaranteed by the standard; the current case doesn't do this explicitly, but what it does is basically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The sample code you posted does not show problems, because it just happens to have the same alignment requirements for both classes (and uses nice even numbers of objects of class A).  I modified your example somewhat to demonstrate what happens if alignof(A) < align of(B) and you use odd numbers of A: http://ideone.com/eC7l17

Now you get this output:

```
B starts at 0x9003008, needs alignment 4, misaligned by 0
B has 0 As
B starts at 0x900306a, needs alignment 4, misaligned by 2
B has 1 As
A[]
B starts at 0x90030cc, needs alignment 4, misaligned by 0
B has 2 As
A[]
A[]
```

and interesting things would happen if you tried to use the misaligned pointer to B (recovered from A[0].

Avi Berger already suggested a fix. I'll try to come up with a generalized template for arbitrary A and B that will do the right thing.

```
| A[N - 1] ... A[0] | <padding> | B |
```

where the padding is computed based on alignof(A) and alignof(B)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to happen when you have one child object dependent of multiple parents. In your case, using raw pointers such as

```
const B* A::getB() const 
{ 
  return (B*)(this + index + 1); 
}
```

or

```
const B* A::getB() const 
{ 
  return (B*)((void*)this + sizeof(A) * (index + 1)); 
}
```

should yield exactly the same pointer arithmetic you want to achieve. What I understood from [this doc](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/download/temp/pdfexport-20130912-120913-1434-3025/cplusplus-EXP14-CPP.Donotusereinterpret_castonpointerstoclassobjectswithmultipleinheritence-120913-1434-3026.pdf?contentType=application/pdf) is (example taken from there):

```
class Base1 {public: virtual ~Base1() {}};
class Base2 {public: virtual ~Base2() {}};
class Derived: public Base1, public Base2 {public: virtual ~Derived() {}};

// ...
Derived obj;
Derived* dp = &obj;
Base1* b1p = dp;
Base2* b2p = dp; // [1]
Derived* dps = static_cast<Derived*>(b2p); // [2]
Derived* dpr = reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(b2p); // [3]
```

`dp` is a pointer to the object `Derived`, which layout is basically something like a concatenation of `Base1`, `Base2` and `Derived` in that order:

```
---- address 1: used by Derived and Base1
---- members of Base1: roughly sizeof(Base1))
---- address 2: used by Base2
---- members of Base2: roughly sizeof(Base2))
---- members of Derived
```

(though I really think this is completely implementation specific, but it is my understanding of the layout).

If you would like to point to the parent `Base2` object within the `Derived` object, the equal operator (line `[1]`) casts correctly to the parent `Base2` address. The `static_cast` operator (line `[2]`) gets back to the original value using the the hierarchy known at compilation time. The `reinterpret_cast` on the oder hand is like a C style cast, and since it operates on a pointer to `Base2`, returns an erroneous pointer to a `Derived` object in `dpr`.

Coming back to your initial question, I do not think you may have any issue as long as their are no dependencies between your two classes in terms of hierarchy. Using casts such as `void *` and explicit pointer arithmetic (`sizeof(A)`) seems however to me more appropriate.

I am curious to know in what extent it will improve the performances in fact against having the array of `A`s and a pointer to the unique `B`.